# Funny bug with missing applications after using Screen Time & Limits

Tags: settings, pantheon-files, applications, code

I wanted a way to lock applications so thought that using Screen Time and Limits, previously called Parental Controls, would be a smart way of doing this by locking applications like Code and Files behind a password.

It hasn't worked.

The problem I have now is those applications have gone from the applications menu and I cant find em. I have reinstalled Code from the App Center which worked but now it has no icon in the applications menu.

How can I get these applications back?

Would it be better to just create a new user and delete this one?

Does anyone know a good way to lock applications?

Comment: Have you removed these apps from the Screen Time & Limits settings?  I assume you have but you do not say.

Comment: Yes I removed them. They're not even showing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reported issues relating to blocking apps but they do not exactly match yours. You can report your issue at https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-parental-controls/issues. Please make sure you give full details regarding which version of elementary you are using and any other relevant info.  Hopefully we can get this working properly by the time Odin is released and you will not need an alternative method.  There is an issue blocking default apps so you could try changing the default to something you do not use.

Comment: Pretty serious problem. I'm going to have to delete my account! elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera.